# (Why?) Image size nearly doubles when uploading to S3 - Django

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-forms, django-views

When I upload an image via Django to Amazon's S3, the image size nearly doubles. For example, I upload an image to Django that is 17.4KB, but when I look at my S3 bucket, the image is 33.2KB.

Is there a reason why this is happening? Below are my forms and views to see the processes. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

***forms.py:***

```
class PhotoUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('photo',)
```

***views.py:***

```
@login_required
def photo_upload(request):
    form = PhotoUploadForm(request.POST or None,
                           request.FILES or None,
                           request=request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.creator = request.user
            obj.slug = get_random_string(length=10)
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
    return render(request, 'photos/photo_upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: There is no upload to s3 happening here. Did you furthermore try downloading the files from s3 again and comparing them against the original file, to see how they differ?

Comment: @ChristopherSchäpers My `STATIC_URL` and 'MEDIA_URL` settings are configured to upload to S3. I did download the image, however. It's the exact same image dimensions, but twice the file size as the original.

Comment: Didn't know `MEDIA_URL` does S3 out of the box, considering you have to install boto for basic AWS functionality everywhere else. What happens if you don't upload it directly to s3? Also try to remove metadata from the downloaded file, to see if the redundant data is metadata, or actual data.

Comment: @ChristopherSchäpers Boto is installed, sorry for not mentioning that. When I upload locally, it's the correct file size. I'm assuming that means it's extra metadata being added. How would I remove that?

Comment: Did you try different images?

Comment: @François Yes, they all double in size.

Comment: So, if you upload a 1MB image, it becomes a 2MB image ?! Also, did you download the image from S3 and compared it with the original?

Comment: @François Yes and yes. Very weird... I know.